# AppleScript: Did Safari’s "do JavaScript" stop working in macOS Monterey?

Tags: applescript, safari, monterey

This used to work in previous OS versions (10.14 and 10.15), but not anymore in macOS 12.0.1 Monterey:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell first tab of first window
        do JavaScript "document.body.style;"
    end tell
end tell
```

... does not yield a result at all. Even worse, tihs produces an error:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell first tab of first window
        set x to do JavaScript "document.body.style;"
    end tell
end tell

log x
```

... will yield: ‘The variable x is not defined.’ Is there anything I can do to make this work or is it a bug in macOS?

Comment: You may need to "Allow Javascript from Apple Events" in Safari!

Comment: Good point, @Wowfunhappy. I looked it up and found that it was on already. I still had to enable Develop > Allow Remote Automation, but to no avail.

Comment: Same here. JS via AppleScript doesn't work with Safari with both mentioned options enabled. It works in Chrome, however.

Comment: The result of the javascript is a complex object. I've only ever used scalar return values, what's the expected AppleScript class type in this case?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. @user3579815 is correct. if the javascript command is returning a (DOM) object via querySelector, 'do javascript' won't return a result.

Comment: if you open Inspect Element in Safari and type `typeof document.body.style`, Safari will tell you that it's an object. so you need to change the javascript code.

here's a sample to get you going:

`do JavaScript "var y = ''; for (let x in document.body.style) { y += x + ': ' + x.value + '\\r' }"`